# LINQ where with variable

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following statement:

```
var itemsFromList = from item in ListItems 
                    where item.Countries != null 
                    select item;
```

So I can return all the values that are present in countries (some are empty).
in the same list I have other columns for instance cities and I have to change it to:

```
var itemsFromList = from item in ListItems 
                    where item.cities != null 
                    select item;
```

Is there a way to use the same statement to return either the cities or countries that are not empty by using a variable a bit like this:

```
var itemsFromList = from item in ListItems 
                    where item.variable != null 
                    select item;
```

Comment: How is `Variable` related to an individual item in a list?

Comment: Your question is very unclear to me - what do you want to achieve?

Comment: What is Variable? What's the link between Variable and ListItems?

Comment: if variable != null, just select the whole list, otherwise, select an empty list. you don't need Linq for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like Variable is meant to be just that, a variable, that is defined at a later date.  If you really want to have your expression be modifiable like that, your best bet is to use Reflection.

First, you'll need to get a reference to the PropertyInfo of the desired property.  You can do this by calling [Type.GetProperty(string name)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy.aspx).  Once you have a reference to the PropertyInfo, you can get the value of a specific instance by calling [PropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx).

Here is an example of creating a LINQ query that will get only items where the specified property is not null.

```
// Declare this as a Generic method of Type T so that we can pass in a
// List containing anything and easily get the appropriate Type object
public static IEnumerable<T> SelectNonNull<T>(
    IEnumerable<T> ListItems, string propertyName)
{
    IEnumerable<T> itemsFromList;
    // Get a reference to the PropertyInfo for the property
    // we're doing a null-check on.
    PropertyInfo variable = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
    if (variable == null)
    {
        // The property does not exist on this item type:
        // just return all items
        itemsFromList = from item in ListItems
                        select item;
    }
    else
    {
        itemsFromList = from item in ListItems
                        // GetValue will check the value of item's
                        // instance of the specified property.
                        where variable.GetValue(item, null) != null
                        select item;
    }
    return itemsFromList;
}
```

To get the results in your question, you could then use this function like so:

```
var NonNullCountries = SelectNonNull(ListItems, "Countries");
var NonNullCities = SelectNonNull(ListItems, "cities");
```

Alternately, we could declare this as an extension method (like the other Linq methods), like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SelectNonNull<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    string propertyName)
{
    PropertyInfo variable = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
    if (variable == null)
    {
        // Specified property does not exist on this item type:
        //just return all items
        return from item in source
                select item;
    }
    else
    {
        return from item in source
                where variable.GetValue(item, null) != null
                select item;
    }
}
```

We could then chain multiple calls together.  For instance, if you wanted to filter out all entries where "cities" AND "Countries" are null, you could just use the following:

```
var NonNullCitiesOrCountries = ListItems.SelectNonNull("Countries")
                                        .SelectNonNull("cities");
```

**Note:** SelectNonNull just returns an IEnuerable.  You will still need to enumerate over it to get at the results of the query.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very unclear, but the [`let`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) clause lets you break out sub-expression results. Possibly this (?):

```
var itemsFromList = from item in ListItems 
                    let Variable = item.Countries
                    where Variable != null 
                    select item;
```

<sub>I'm not sure what this would actually achieve.</sub>

My only other thought is that you don't know what `Variable` is at compile-time and want to inject something?

As @DarenThomas says, if the `Variable` is actually external to the Linq statement the entire statement becomes defunct because `Variable` won't potentially change on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to replace the hard-coded field `Country` with something dynamic.

In that case, you need to declare `Variable` (let's call it `getNotNullField` instead) as a function from `ListItem` to `object`:

```
Func<ListItem, object> getNotNullField;
if (...) {
    getNotNullField = item => item.Countries;
} else {
    getNotNullField = item => item.SomeOtherField;
}

...

var itemsFromList = from item in ListItems where getNotNullField(item) != null 
                    select item;
```